# In GA4 is it possible to create custom user/session acquisition properties?

Tags: google-analytics-4

I like the new user acquisition properties, for they do what I think. Tell me how the user first came to the website.

Is it possible to add custom user acquisition properties to add to the data collected. e.g. the first page they ever visited ('user page location'). This could help value pages.

There are the user custom properties but as far as I can see they don't show up in the relevant reports, and I'm not sure how to only set them on the users first page view.

A similar 'session page location' would also be of use, like the landing page report in Universal.